# What does "Bellifreschi" mean as a film title?

Tags: word-meaning, cinema

What does film title "[Bellifreschi](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellifreschi)" mean? The search results for "bellofresco" only give links to cafés and a Dutch wine shop. Is it colloquial/slang?

Comment: Without having seen the movie, it is composed of *belli* (beautiful) and *freschi* (fresh). It could mean "We are fresh and beautiful* or it could be a reference to the expression *stiamo freschi* (meaning *We are in a bad position*)

Comment: @DenisNardin So it's just a compound of _bello_ and _fresco_ and there is no any completely different sense like in f.e. _un dolcevita_?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. It is probably a reference to something in the movie, but as I said I have not seen it

Comment: I agree with Denis, and add that in _belli freschi_ (two words), the word _belli_ may also simply strengthen _freschi_: you might say _Qui in montagna stiamo belli freschi_ (Here on the mountains we are [= the climate is] nicely cool). Then again, as Denis says, one should check if it refers to something explicitly mentioned in the film (a band name, say?).

Comment: *Bellifreschi* is a [comic movie](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellifreschi) about a couple of extemely unlucky jazz singers aspiring to glory that accidentally become two of the most wanted criminals of USA. To get away from the police they dress up as women and struggling alone against incredible and comic odds they are at last arrested. They manage to escape police again accidentally killing everybody and finally they met in Mexico with new identity and new life. As pointed out by @DenisNardin in the first comment, in the movie they are in a very bad position...

Comment: @abarisone: So, probably this title refers to the expression "stiamo belli e freschi" with the meaning explained  [here](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/F/fresco.shtml)?

Comment: It could be a good explanation, since even if it's a comic movie the two main characters always end up in troubles, big troubles.

Comment: Ascertained that it is not a “real” word, the only way to learn more is actually watching the film (I'll leave someone else the pleasure, it's not exactly my cup of tea). But a small clue comes from Paolo Mereghetti's _Dizionario dei film_ (giving it a single star, the minimum in a 4-star scale), which mentions that there are explicit references to _Some like it hot_, which would partially explain the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @DenisNardin ***Bellifreschi*** is composed of belli (beautiful) and freschi (fresh). It could mean "We are fresh and beautiful* or it could be a reference to the expression *stiamo freschi* (meaning *We are in a bad position*).

In fact the Treccani dictionary for *[stare fresco](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fresco1/)* states:

> Fig., iron., stare fresco, essere nei guai, andare incontro a un
> castigo, a una lavata di capo, e sim.: *se lo viene a sapere papà, stiamo freschi!;*
> (figuratively to be in bad position, to be about to be grounded, reprimended)

To better understand the meaning it can also be said that ***Bellifreschi*** is a [comic movie](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellifreschi) about a couple of extemely unlucky jazz singers aspiring to glory that accidentally become two of the most wanted criminals of USA. To get away from the police they dress up as women and, struggling alone against incredible and comic odds, they are at last arrested. They manage to escape police again accidentally killing everybody and finally they met in Mexico with new identity and new life.

Ascertained that it is not a “real” word, a small clue comes from Paolo Mereghetti's *Dizionario dei film* (giving it a single star, the minimum in a 4-star scale), which mentions that there are explicit references to *Some like it hot*, which would partially explain the title. (Thanks to @DaG)